# Move a few commits from a feature branch to its parent

Tags: git

I've messed up a little bit and did the following.

I've branched from `master` to `feature` and made a few commits on the actual feature.

Then, while still on the `feature` branch, I've made a few commits which should've actually be made in `master`. So, instead of making a few commits in `master` and then `rebase`ing `feature`, I made a few commits in the `feature` branch.

The first thing I tried was `rebase`ing `master`, but it included all the commits on the actual feature. But I only want to selectively include those specific commits made in the `feature` branch by mistake!

So, is there a chance I can do this and not break future `feature` rebases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cherry-picking is the way to do this, but since rebasing is effectively automated bulk cherry-picking:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i master
# move all commits you wish to be on master to top of list

git log
# find last (most-recent) commit you wish to be on master

git checkout master
git reset --hard <sha from above>
```